# How to Extract all the values form the regular expression extractor and pass the all value to parameter of the http request

Tags: jmeter

Here is the sample view

Home  Home

I have tried
$1$$21$$41$$61$$81$$101$$121$$141$$161$$181$$201$$221$$241$$261$$281$$301$

but its not get correct value

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions could be:

1. Create a user-defined variable, suppose "my_variable"
2. Create a "Regular Expression" which will list all the values from the response, Test it using expression tester
3. Now under the sample from where you want to extract the information, create a JSR223 Post Processor and use the sample code as per below:

[image: Code Details]

Comment: Thank very much Pushpendra it works for me and sample code is very useful .

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing:

1. Full (or at least partial) response containing the "values" you want to extract
2. How you're going to re-use them in the next request

One thing is obvious: [using regular expressions for extracting values from HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), I would recommend going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead, given your response data:

```
<a class="main mainAnchor current currentAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form1"> <span>Home</span> <a
        class="main mainAnchor parent parentAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form2"><a
        class="main mainAnchor current currentAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form3"> <span>Home</span> <a
        class="main mainAnchor parent parentAnchor" tabindex="-1" href="Form4">
```

You can extract all href attributes of the `<a>` element as simple as:

[image]

More information: [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri yes I am will try to use CSS selector Extractor Thank you for given good Idea its very helpful